# Responsive navbar / dropdown menu shows links. How to align it right, below hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive, hamburger-menu

Im trying to fix my navbar, but in the mobile version, the hamburger icon, which is on the right, displays the menu list on the left, instead of showing right,below the icon. Also, when clicked, the whole navbar moves up, and the icon gets lost. Thx in advance, I will much appreciate some guidance. I've tried so many things with the classes/CSS file. codepen ->[link](https://codepen.io/lunainde/pen/wvzXBdd). [desktop & mobile look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcQKj.png)

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
      <!-----left---->
      <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-lu">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="fixed">
          <div>
            <h6 id="nav-h6"><strong>I'm Luna</strong></h6>
            <p id="nav-p">a <span class="highlight">ux/ui</span> designer</p>
          </div>
          <!-----toggler---->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#top">home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#work">work</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#top">home</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#work">work</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#about">about</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" data-turbo-method="delete" href="#">Log out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </div>
```

---

```
/* ---NAVBARLU--- */
.navbar-lu {
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
}
.navbar-lu .navbar-collapse {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.navbar-lu .navbar-brand img {
  width: 40px;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0rem;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  /* keeps navbar on top of items when scrolling */
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: black;
  /* border: none; */
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* border: none; */
}
#nav-p {
  margin: 0rem;
}
#nav-h6 {
  margin: 0rem;
}
.nav-link {
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0rem;
  /* justify-content: end; */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position fixed needs top, if you add `top: 0;` to #fixed, it'll work.

Comment: Thank you, that part is solved! much appreciated
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;